# Pandas.to_datetime() fails only on column from Data Frame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I apologize for the title to this, but couldn't figure out a way to phrase it better.

When I try to run

```
pd.to_datetime(df['TimeStamp'], format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
```

I receive the following exception:

```
time data '2019-01-06 15:34:19.000' doesn't match format specified
```

This time is that contained in the first row of my data frame. It sure seemed to be in the specified format, so I tested it by manually copy-pasting a few rows from the TimeStamp column directly into the Series constructor:

```
tempSeries = pd.Series(['2019-01-06 15:34:19.023', '2019-01-06 15:34:19.000'])
```

When I call `pd.to_datetime(tempSeries, format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')` , things works fine.

I should be able to pass the series in as in my first example, correct? Can anyone make a suggestion as to what might be going on?

**EDIT:**

As requested, here is `df['TimeStamp].head().to_dict()`:

```
{0: "'2019-01-06 15:36:19.000'",
 1: "'2019-01-06 15:37:19.000'",
 2: "'2019-01-06 15:38:19.000'",
 3: "'2019-01-06 15:39:19.000'",
 4: "'2019-01-06 15:40:19.000'"}
```

Comment: `pd.to_datetime(tempSeries, format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')` works fine for me. :)

Comment: It works fine for me. Can you paste `df.head().to_dict()` ?

Comment: @anky_91: tempSeries works fine for me, too. It's only when I call the function and pass in the Series using df['TimeStamp'] notation that it bombs. Sorry if I wasn't clear.

Comment: @harvpan I added the head as you requested.

Comment: Wow. Try `pd.to_datetime(df['Timestamp'].str.strip("'"))`

Comment: You need to change the for mat to `format="'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f'"` You can see that your strings are single and double quoted.

Comment: Thanks very much, both of you. That was it: dumb oversight on my part. I'll gladly mark it as the answer it you post it as one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see that your strings are single and double quoted.

You need to change the format to

```
format="'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f'"
```

Or

Use

```
pd.to_datetime(df['Timestamp'].str.strip("'")) #cs95
```